# Cannot share shared preferences between remote service and activity in an application?

Tags: sharedpreferences

I tried using MULTI_MODE_PROCESS above API Level 11. But still I am not getting updating values in activity and values were updated in remote service. I am not able to share preferences in remote service and activity even in froyo,ginger bread versions.Is this a bug in Android ?  Any solution we have for this ?

Comment: Anyone available to answer my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Without code, it's not clear exactly what you're doing, but my guess is that you did the same thing I did at first: simply change your existing call to `getSharedPreferences()` to use `MULTI_MODE_PROCESS` and expect synchronization.  That's not enough; you also must call `getSharedPreferences()` again (with the multi-process flag) before accessing the SharedPreferences that may have been changed by another process.